# What is about nonassociative geometry?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, jordan-algebras

At the end of a conference given by Alain Connes in 2000 ([here](http://www.canal-u.tv/video/universite_de_tous_les_savoirs/mathematiques_du_monde_quantique.1033) is a video in French), a member of the audience asked a question. I transcribed and translated it for you below:

**Audience:** You showed that noncommutative geometry greatly simplifies the physics in a very elegant way, by actually losing a property that seems a bit simple. Similary, if we work with algebras, complex numbers, quaternions and octonions..., are there people investigating some nonassociative geometries?
**Alain Connes:** Ok, I can explain you about this right now...

The video cuts off at that time, even before Alain finishes his explanation, so I post this question here :

> What is about nonassociative geometry
>   ?

**Sir Michael Atiyah** ([here](https://youtu.be/zCCxOE44M_M) at 58'): Connes' theory is very beautiful, but it only deals with associative algebras, so it can't deals with the octonions, so that's why I think this theory is not quite finished.

Comment: If you look on google you find some stuff, for example: http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9607086v2.pdf

Comment: Thank you for this reference. I also found 15 papers on arxiv containing nonassociative (or non-associative) geometry on their title, the most recent in 2013, but your reference is the first (1997). Just a note: on the 15 references found, 11 were tagged by "High Energy Physics", 2 by "Quantum algebra" and one by "Ring and algebra." It seems that the physicists are much more motivated by the nonassociative geometry than the mathematicians, why ?

Comment: Michael Atiyah speculates about the role for octonion-based geometries for quantum gravity around 30 minutes and 54 minutes into this talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1ftUA17MZg. Also, after 58 minutes comes the thought that we need to go beyond cyclic homology for associative algebras to deal with nonassociativity.

Comment: Thank you very much David, this video is very interesting. I will put, in the issue, a quotation of Michael Atiyah extract from this video.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is progress in this direction by mathematicians here: [Jordan operator algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_operator_algebra)

(see also this *Physics* post : [Non-associative operators in Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67266/non-associative-operators-in-physics))

**Warning**:  the Jordan operator algebras *exchange* the associativity by the commutativity, in fact their product $\circ$, given by $a_1 \circ a_2 = \frac{1}{2}(a_1*a_2+a_2*a_1)$, is commutative nonassociative, whereas $*$ is noncommutative associative.  So it's an advanced but it's not really satisfying.
A satisfying advanced would be with nonassociative **and** noncommutative algebras.